# is there a sure fire way to find css postions?

Tags: css

I have taken many peoples advice in using css for website layouts vs tables. I have a decent understanding in CSS, but there is one thing I am left wondering. That is, is finding the right position just guess and check, or is there a way to find it with a more precise answer the first time.

Currently what I am doing is putting in a position to see where it lands, and then make multiple adjustments until it is where I want it. To me this seems a little barbaric and like there has to be a better way to do this.

So is there a better way of finding the right position?

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: Position for what?  Floating elements is favored over absolute positioning for most layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Planning your design and layout, knowing CSS and how it works.  Practice.  I can draw a design on a piece of paper, label out its sizes, and then write down on that piece of paper the CSS and be 100% dead on with the layout once coded out and tested in a live environment.  Simply because I plan my design, take my time to do the math to come up with my css values, and I know which css values do what, when to use them, and how to use them.

Best advice, keep on reading and learning as much as possible.  Start doing simple wireframe sketches, at the least, of your designs before you code them, and mark each element and space up with a desired size, then use those numbers when you make your design.

Lastly, not sure if this is true or not, but it sounds like you are simply using absolute positioning?  If so, learn how to use relative positioning, floats, margins, padding, etc.  While it can be more complicated, it is a much more dynamic and flexible way of building a site, and you can do much cleaner designs that work on all browsers and look right on all browsers, not just a few under controlled conditions.

Comment: I can get a rough idea when I am using percentages, but when it comes to pixels, I have a harder time figuring out where exactly I am going to end up. For the most part I have been using absolute, but I have been trying out the margins, floats, and padding. Thanks for your advice on furthing my skills in CSS, it is appreciated.

Comment: http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/web-development-tutorials/psdhtml-conversion-code-a-clean-business-website-design/#more-3562

Comment: That is a decent tutorial on taking a photoshop design, and converting it into HTML/CSS... not perfect, they use images many times where you could use text instead, and several other non-best-practices, but it is a good start and explains fairly well the thought behind the sizing and positioning.

Comment: Lastly, another good way to get better is to try and build some layouts, not text or content, just give the elements heights and widths, and background color, and see if you can get the layout done... for example, try and mock up these designs http://www.accent45.com/web/web-design/

Answer (score -1):

**This is the way it is done**

but if you want to do that use Photoshop or any designing tool to used to create the design of the website and check the position and then try giving it in the CSS. i am sure it will not be the perfect but you will be close